# My storage doesn't exist

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I have a samsung S3 mini GT-18190.It shows that the internal storage is 16GB available space and phone storage is 17MB. But when I plug my GT-18190 to my computer only 17MB partition displays. A 16GB partion doesn't display.Please can u help me for this problem.

Comment: There is only that partition accessible on a non-rooted device. If you want access to the 'root' folders, you need root access basically. The rest is the cache, the Android OS, system apps and data etc. If I plug in an S4 I get "Phone Storage" and "External SD Card" options only as I would expect.

Comment: It will show external memory also by default. You must have changed something.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have right drivers intalled on PC for your phone.

Try rebooting after that.

Regards.